# JavaScript ternary operator calling function or no-op

Tags: javascript

What is best practice for debugging in JavaScript?

```
debugging ? console.log('info') : null;
```

My question is the `null`, what is standard practice for this in general, or in this debugging use case?

Answer (score 13):

In your case:

`debugging && console.log('info');`

This trick is based on the "short circuit" feature and I suppose this info might be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation